# escape strings correctly into JSON data in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have some rather long string containing just about anything that I want to convert to JSON from PHP. Is there a simple way to do this? For example I would like this JSON ouput to work:

```
<?php
   $var = "hel\"lo";
   $var2 = "hel\nlo";
   echo "[\"".$var."\", \"".$var2."\"]"; // should give me the data: hel"lo and hel<new line>lo
?>
```

Comment: In case the answers didn't make it clear enough, use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: @Wesley why do you feel the need to re-post all the 5 correct answers as a comment?

Comment: @Matthieu: I didn't see the need for the 6th answer, so I just left a comment to enforce the others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Construct a PHP data structure and then run it through [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). Don't try to build JSON by mashing together strings.

```
$foo = array($var, $var2);
echo json_encode($foo);
```

Comment: @Salman A — Not properly. It outputs a string. Since the top level data type in JSON must be an array or an object, it should throw an exception instead of outputting anything. That is beside the point though, the question is about an array.

Answer (score 3):

You could use json_encode (EDIT - i changed the array so that when encoded the output is what was requested)

```
var $json = array('hello','hello');

echo (json_encode($json));
```

look [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for reference.

EDIT - to use json_encode you must have php vesion > 5.20 . if you need an alternative you can use the zend_framework component [Zend_JSON](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.json.html)

Comment: The target is an array, not an object, that `=>` should be a `,`.

Comment: @Quentin `=>` is a language construct for arrays, not objects. This enables to specify on the left the array key, and on the right the array value. You can then do : `$value = $myarray['hello'];`. However, the OP seems to want `array('hello', 'hello')` anyway.

Comment: It0s an associative array, as key -> value so you have a json object with a property named hello with a value of hello, but yes, the question asked for what you wrote! :)

Comment: @Matthieu — It is a language construct for PHP associative arrays which map onto JSON **objects**. Numerically indexed arrays (which map onto JSON arrays) are created with a simple list of values and no explicit keys. The example in the question makes it clear that a JSON array is desired.

Answer (score 3):

```
$var = "hel\"lo";
$var2 = "hel\nlo";
echo json_encode(array($var, $var2));
```

Answer (score 2):

json_encode and json_decode should do the trick.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:
[Json - encode a PHP function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)